# Plus equals with ruby send message

Tags: ruby

I'm getting familiar with ruby send method, but for some reason, I can't do something like this

```
a = 4
a.send(:+=, 1)
```

For some reason this doesn't work. Then I tried something like

```
a.send(:=, a.send(:+, 1))
```

But this doesn't work too. What is the proper way to fire plus equals through 'send'?

Comment: There is no such method `+=`, it simply shortcut to `a = a + 1`, so you could write `a = a.send(:+, 1)` if you have to use `send` method.

Comment: To expound, `+=` is handled at the lexer level, and expanded into its long form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the basic option is only:

```
a = a.send(:+, 1)
```

That is because `send` is for messages to objects. Assignment modifies a variable, not an object.

---

It is possible to assign direct to variables with some meta-programming, but the code is convoluted, so far the best I can find is:

```
a = 1
var_name = :a
eval "#{var_name} = #{var_name}.send(:+, 1)"
puts a  # 2
```

Or using instance variables:

```
@a = 2
var_name = :@a
instance_variable_set( var_name, instance_variable_get( var_name ).send(:+, 1) )
puts @a  # 3
```

Comment: Your last example could skip `var_name` assignment and just do this instead: `@a = 2; instance_variable_set(:@a, instance_variable_get(:@a).send(:+,1)); => 3`

Comment: @d3ven: Yes, it was a while ago now, but I think I have kept the `var_name` in there for easier visual comparison between the two approaches. You could also `eval "a = a.send(:+, 1)"` in the first example . . . so `var_name` is just standing in for "you can choose this dynamically" in any case.

Answer (score 1):

See the below :

```
p 4.respond_to?(:"+=") #  false
p 4.respond_to?(:"=")  #  false
p 4.respond_to?(:"+")  #  true
```

`a+=1` is syntactic sugar of `a = a+1`. But there is no direct method `+=`. `=` is an assignment operator,not the method as well. On the other hand `Object#send` takes method name as its argument. Thus your code will not work,the way you are looking for.

Comment: You should use `:"+="` and `:"="` to avoid the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Ruby doesn't have `=` method. In Ruby `=` don't work like in C/C++ but it rather assign new object reference to variable, not assign new value to variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a method on `a`, because `a` is not an object, it's a variable, and variables aren't objects in Ruby. You are calling a method on `4`, but `4` is not the thing you want to modify, `a` is. It's just not possible.

Note: it is certainly possible to define a method named `=` or `+=` and call it, but of course those methods will only exist on objects, not variables.

```
class Fixnum
  define_method(:'+=') do |n| self + n end
end

a = 4

a.send(:'+=', 1)
# => 5

a
# => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This might miss the mark a bit, but I was trying to do this where `a` is actually a method dynamically called on an object. For example, with attributes like `added_count` and `updated_count` for `Importer` I wrote the following

```
class Importer
  attr_accessor :added_count, :updated_count

  def increment(method)
    send("#{method}=", (send(method) + 1))
  end

end
```

So I could use `importer.increment(:added_count)` or `importer.increment(:updated_count)`

Now this may seem silly if you only have these 2 different counters but in some cases we have a half dozen or more counters and different conditions on which attr to increment so it can be handy.